TRS headphone jack wiring
Summary:
I have an in-ear-headphone that I am trying to replace the TRS jack for.  I have tried soldering the wires to a jack a couple of times with the same no-good result.  The left speaker doesn't separate from the right, and when both speakers are supposed to be going, the sound level drops.  I suspect that somehow I got the wirings of the cable confused, but searching for a similar cable / attachment instructions has proven unfruitful so far, so here I am.
Cable:

Cut cable
Cut cable, crossed-section
With the outer insulation stripped off, seeing only the red strands around an inner tube
With the red strands twisted together, also seeing the red inner tube
The inner insulation stripped, with greenish/bluish wire strands
Same as 4, but seeing a bit of white wire strands mixed in with the greenish/bluish wire strands







Trial
Description
Seeing that there appeared to be only two bunches without ground wires, I burned off the coating for the red wires and twisted them together, did the same with the green/blue wires, and then soldered them to the TRS jack, blue/green to the left, and red to the right, with no ground.

Result
I then tested it using one of youtube test videos, with sound sent to the left speaker, to the right speaker, and then to both.  What I heard was both speakers, both speakers, and then both speakers with reduced volume.
Suspicion and Questions
I suspect that I messed up the wirings somehow, but can't tell any differences in the wires.  Where is ground?  Why such results on the speakers?  What do I need to do to get this right?

Green left, blue right or vise versa. Red ground

@RussellH  Thanks for the help.  This would have solved the problem for me, even if I might not have understood any better.  I didn't think of this because the blue and green wires aren't insulated additionally from each other.  You were right from the get go, though.  Green to the left, and blue to the right.

They have to be insulated from each other. There are some coatings that melt or boil away when heated, allowing them to be soldered without stripping off the insulation.. Glad it works. Cheers.

You had three different colors and yet soldered to only two terminals, left and right outputs.
If you hear all aounds from both buds, it means you must have headset ground on one output and both left and right bud wires on the other output.
Since you used red on one and both blue and green on other, red might be ground.
You can verify with a multimeter by measuring resistance between all three wires. Ground will have about equal resistance to left and right wires. Measuring left and right wires will show sum of both buds.
Measuring with a multimeter will apply small voltage to the driver so you migh hear clicks from the bud when connecting and disconnecting the meter probes. You can identify which wire is left and right and ground.

Hello, thanks for the answer.  I honestly wasn't thinking about how the speakers worked: was just trying to follow some magic instruction about red + green/blue wires.Thanks for the instructions.  I got a multimeter and did the test you suggested.  Green to the left, blue to the right, and red is ground.  It worked!
